# What do I need to remove and replace this recessed faucet aerator?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I've got a bathroom sink faucet with a recessed (cache) aerator that needs to be cleaned or replaced, but seems to require a special tool to remove it.  There is no obvious branding on the faucet, so I don't know what removal tool to ask or look for.

I've tried some of the "standard" removal keys they sell at the big box stores, but they don't fit.  Those keys seem to be a little too big and you can tell that the tooth pattern is not quite right.

I've included pictures of the faucet, the aerator, and a key that does *not* fit.

Wondering if anyone knows what kit or tool I need to remove and replace this aerator?

Image of faucet here:
[image]

Close-up of aerator:

[image]

Example of key that did not work:
[image]

+++ Update +++

Thanks to @Alaska-man, it turns out the tip of the faucet itself was threaded and, once removed, gave me direct access to the aerator (which is not itself threaded).
Don't know why I didn't think to to try this.  Perhaps because the visible part of the aerator had grooves that convinced me that it was itself threaded.

Images of tip and aerator removed. Also, it's apparently a Delta faucet (discovered after removing tip and observing lettering on underside).

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a Kohler sink - any chance it's also a Kohler faucet?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier and cheaper to simply close your valves  a bit? At any rate, those things aren't typically very tight. A pair of small slotted screwdrivers (or similar) should do fine.

Comment: Is the flared part of the faucet, the ring around the end, able to turn. It may be threaded and holding the the aerator in. Meaning the the aerator is not threaded in but being held in by the ring. ?? If you can not get it out you could put some CLR or vinegar in ziplock type bag and tape it on the faucet so that the aerator is soaking in the liquid.

Comment: @Alaskaman Good call on trying to turn the ring.  It actually was threaded, came off, and gave me access to the aerator.  The aerator itself was just held in there by the ring (aerator had no threads at all).  If you want to write up an "answer" (vice a comment), I can "accept" it and give you credit.

Comment: i will post it as an answer so you choose at correct. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flared part of the faucet, the ring around the end, should turn. It should be threaded and holding the the aerator in.

Meaning the the aerator is not threaded in but is being held in by a threaded retention ring. ??

Answer (score 2):

[image]I used to back side of a caliper. It's adjustable so it'll fit any diameter aerator. Very simple and it worked beautifully.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer, but I hope it's a cheap caliper... And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

I used a pair of needle nosed pliers.  Slid the ends into the tiny plastic indents and turned.  Worked like a charm.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Pfister Faucet but can't be sure - you would need to remove it and look underneath for the make / model information. Just looking at Pfister with the outside crown on the aerator - I am pretty sure that is what you have.

A Pair of Snap Ring pliers for small snap rings would allow you to remove it - a 90 or 60 degree bend at the nose would be very helpful. That is what I would use to remove this given I did not have a tool - I might look to order one after I removed it though.

Kohler looks to be the same style as the Pfister I have seen so it is possible this is what you need Kohler 1130269 Aerator Tool .

Answer (score 0):

One can use a paperclip to unscrew it if you don't have the tools. Bend the paperclip so you can stick one end against one of the teeth and push. Once the teeth are protruded, you can use your fingernail against the teeth to remove it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.